# mscorlib: Error: Cannot find module 'crypto' after using Webpack on an application

Tags: node.js, azure, webpack, azure-functions, openpgp.js

I've got a project which utilizes the openpgpjs library as a dependency, and I'm WebPacking up this whole application for deployment on an Azure Functions to 
[resolve cold start issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/298).

The Azure functions work fine when running locally in a non-Webpacked format, but as soon as I WebPack up the files I keep getting the error at runtime:

"mscorlib: Error: Cannot find module 'crypto'"

The code which is triggering this error appears to be from Openpgpjs's util.js.

This whole file is here:
https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/blob/master/src/util.js

The offending code snipper is below:

```
/**
   * Get native Node.js crypto api. The default configuration is to use
   * the api when available. But it can also be deactivated with config.use_native
   * @return {Object}   The crypto module or 'undefined'
   */
  getNodeCrypto: function() {
    if (!this.detectNode() || !config.use_native) {
      return;
    }

    return require('crypto');
  },
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out why this is happening and I can't get the error to go away.

[I'm using my own script pack-git to do the Webpacking](https://github.com/securityvoid/pack-git), etc. However, I get the same behavior if I use [Azure's function pack](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-pack). (Which didn't exist when I started writing the code for master-pack.

As a result I *think* this has something to do with the way the library is playing with WebPack, but I'm not sure where to begin in figuring it out/troubleshooting.

Does anyone have any ideas on what is going wrong, or at least ideas to help me further isolate the problem?

------------------- EDIT ---------------------

I've created a simple project that reproduces the issue when run through Funcpack, which is using Webpack.

Reproduction Steps:

1. Install funcpack, and azure-functions-cli globally:

   npm install -g funcpack azure-functions-cli
2. Clone the following repo:

   git clone https://github.com/securityvoid/funcpack-bug.git
3. Run an npm install while in the folder you cloned into:

   npm install
4. Start the Azure Function with azure-functions-cli from within the base of the cloned repository.

   func run aaaa
5. Navigate to the following URL and validate you get a blank page back, which shows its working:

   http://localhost:7071/Test
6. Stop the azure-functions-cli by closing the window.
7. Run funcpack in the base of the directory:

   funcpack
8. Repeat steps 4-5

NOTE: This time you get an error about the module crypto not being found.

Comment: Hey, this is because this is a native module. I've got a feature to allow you to ignore modules in a feature branch right now. I'm going to try and merge to master and publish an update tonight.

Comment: Awesome! Thank-you!

Comment: Okay, I still have issues even running the dev branch that has those changes merged.

Comment: Hey I've updated the latest release on npm. Can you try again with crypto added to your ignored modules list? You can see a sample of that config here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-pack/blob/master/sample/funcpack.config.json

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT No luck :-(. Still reproduces the issue.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT If you pull the git repo https://github.com/securityvoid/funcpack-bug.git you can see for yourself. Its a really quick, simple repro.

Comment: Cool. I'll take a look. I've a few guesses at what might cause that. I'll check that I'm actually passing the config properly. If so, it's like a webpack issue I'll have to try to debug (since this is basically a utility script about webpack).